# Window style from an external (dll) resource dictionary doesn't apply in design mode

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2022, resourcedictionary, .net-4.8

I created an external control library which holds some resource dictionaries etc. My problem is when I try to apply a style on a `Window` element. The style's changes are visible only when running, and not in the Visual Studio designer.

An example of the resource dictionary from my control library:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="Window_Style" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF272727"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is how I include my external resource dictionary into my app:

```
<Application x:Class="SigmaLibMaster.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SigmaLibMaster"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/SigmaLib;component/Resources/Styles/Window.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

And how I apply it to my window element:

```
<Window x:Class="SigmaLibMaster.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SigmaLibMaster"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="840"
        Style="{DynamicResource Window_Style}">

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sometimes find that resources from libraries don't work at design time.

It's a bug IMO.

The work round I use is design time resources.

This is a mechanism which was originally intended for blend. But the wpf designer in visual studio is the same designer as blend now.

I have a library called uilib.

In the properties of that I add a resource dictionary called DesignTimeResources.xaml. It must be that name.

In the csproj I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Page Include="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml" Condition="'$(DesignTime)'=='true' OR ('$(SolutionPath)'!='' AND Exists('$(SolutionPath)') AND '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'!='true' AND '$(BuildingInsideExpressionBlend)'!='true')">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
</Page>
```

Note particularly that ContainsDesignTimeResources tag.

That merges a bunch of resource dictionaries I have in uilib:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UILib">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UILib;component/Resources/Geometries.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UILib;component/Resources/ControlTemplates.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UILib;component/Resources/FontResources.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UILib;component/Resources/UILibResources.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UILib;component/Resources/HypsoColoursRD.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It will not merge these resources in an extra time when you build. The conditions in the tags mean it's design time only.
You can probably find a bunch more on this by searching now you know it exists.

https://dennymichael.net/2016/07/28/wpf-design-time-resources-dictionary/

Edit

Having tried this with the code supplied, there's a complication here with usage of x:Type Window.

MainWindow is not a window, it's a MainWindow.

The designer doesn't seem to want to work out MainWindow inherits from Window.

If I change that style to:

```
<Style x:Key="MainWindow_Style" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

This then works for me in my designer.

[image]

Comment: A couple of questions. **[1]** The `DesignTimeResources.xaml` should be placed into **properties** folder of my `Library` project? **[2]** My `MergedDictionaries` should be added into `DesignTimeResources.xaml` which we created before? **[3]** And what should I do from my application project, just what I showed in my example? Because I do exactly as you wrote and as the link says and it doesn't "work"!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by doesn't "work"?  If your window is in the application project and you don't get the styles applied then the design time merging needs to be in that project ( as well ).

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean that my `window` doesn't get the style in design mode. And yes, my `window` is into a separate application project!!! In that case, should I create the `DesignTimeResources.xaml` into **properties** folder of my application project and do my merges in there and not into my `Library` project?

Comment: You will need it in your entry point. If you don't do any styling directly on controls in your external library then you don't need it there.  Windows are a bit tricky as well incidentally since they have a window tag but their type is not actually a window. They're a mainwindow or whatever.

Comment: I would usually only have one window in a wpf app BTW. A window is a content control. I usually define UI in usercontrols and template that out from viewmodels @Simos Sigma

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for this. Drove me crazy - stopped working when I switched from 2017 to 2022. This worked great!

Comment: @Nik can you please share with me the exact steps you made so to make it work? Because it doesn't work for me at all!

Comment: @SimosSigma, pretty much just followed the answer exactly.
Important points:
- Make sure it is named `DesignTimeResources.xaml` in Properties folder, 
- edit the csproj exactly as Andy stated.
- Other than that, make sure you're using pack URIs. 
Hope this helps

Comment: @Nik I am doing all this but nothing... The `DesignTimeResources.xaml` file should be placed into Properties folder of the Library or Application?

Comment: Please take a look here [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/15IsXalTjUs9_B0Ss4Vpmf9FkqEudIIRJ/view?usp=share_link ]. Am I doing it right?

Comment: The problem here is because MainWindow is a MainWindow, not a Window. If you change that to x:Type Control from xType WIndow then it'll work. Or it does for me anyhow.

Comment: @Andy: Yes it works for me too, but if I do this, to change `TargetType` to `Control`, I loose the ability to style properties of `Window` element like `BorderThickness`, `BorderBrush` etc. Is this a bug or something? Can I do something about that?

Comment: You'd have to re template your window to do that anyhow. Personally, I just have the one window in my apps so it's a non issue for me. A window is just a content control. Bear in mind the designer is kind of approximate anyhow. It's not exactly a rarity to find what you see running an app is different.

Comment: I'll have one `Window` too. I just wanted to have a basic `Window` style into my `Library` for anytime I want to use one so to not have to write style code again and again. What do you mean to re-template my `Window`?

Comment: How much styling are you really going to put on a window?  How many apps are you thinking of writing?  If you want to see your settings applied in the designer I would think it's far less trouble to just set those on your one window.  Did you try borderthickness?  It's the border around the window content rather than the border round the window. If that content border is what you want then you can set that on the parent level usercontrol(s) form the content of your window.

Comment: @Andy: Finally it just need to change style's target type from `Window` to `Control`. Even if I don't use this `DesignTimeResources.xaml` stuff, it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

As ***Andy*** commented into his answer, "*The problem here is because `MainWindow` is a `MainWindow`, not a `Window`. If you change that to `x:Type Control` from `xType Window` then it'll work*".

So in my case, code stays as it is in my question and I just need to change `<Style x:Key="MainWindow_Style" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">` to `<Style x:Key="MainWindow_Style" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">`. Even if I don't use this `DesignTimeResources.xaml` stuff, it works!!!